# How to send a file from producer to consumer in kafka using spring boot?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

I am having a kafka program to send a single message from producer and it is consumed by the consumer successfully.But i have a question is there any way to send a file instead of a single text message..If yes How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send whatever you want in Kafka. Kafka won't infere anything from your data, it will handle it as a simple array of bytes. However be careful about the size of your Kafka record, some cluster parameters like message.max.bytes ( and many other) have to be updated accordingly.

So to answer your question, just read your file using any kind of IO reader ( depending on your programming language) and just send your file using a bytes or String serializer.

Yannick

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yannick .But what's the problem is i just choose a file from my local source and serialized then i send it to the consumer ,what happens is the \n (new line) \t(tab) is added with the content of the file automatically for each line....... is it will do like that?

Comment: You can control this behavior directly from your code, if you treat your file as a byte array and send it directly as bytes in Kafka, you will have the exact same thing whe' reading from your consumer.